# Questions in Ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
    data: {
        //some data
    },
    url: "http://mydomain.com/checkRequest.php?jsoncallback=?",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result[0].data.NameB == "") {
            alert("123");
        } else {
            alert("456");
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    }
}); // end of ajax
```

I have the above code, it works successfully if and only if there are somethings return.
However, if the PHP does not return anything, the string becomes:   `jQuery191025216468679718673_1364086240540([]);`

and I expected it to go to else's part, which alert 456. But, it skips the whole success function. So, how should I modify the coding?

It works if I change the if clause to `if (result!="")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Have a look at the console.](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) I'm sure you get an error like

> Cannot read property "data" of undefined.

If the array is empty, `result[0]` will return `undefined` and the subsequent property access will cause a run time error, which terminates the script immediately. Check first whether the arrays is empty or not:

```
if (result.length > 0 && result[0].data.NameB == "")
```

You might have to test the existence of `result[0].data` as well, depending on the data.